# ui-grid cannot rendered correctly when using ng-show/ng-hide, if you press F12 on the keyboard, it can do it correctly

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid, ng-show, ng-hide

My code is as below:

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions" ng-show="flag"></div>
```

when i set the flag to true, the grid cannot render correctly, if you press F12 on the keyboard, it can show correctly!

Comment: ng-grid also has this issue!

Comment: what do you mean by Correctly? doesnt show at all?

Comment: does it show correctly if you resize your browser window? if that's the case then you might need to call gridApi.core.refresh(); when you change your flag variable (that's for ui-grid. for ng-grid i think you need to call gridOptions.ngGrid.buildColumns(); )

Comment: @OriPrice, it means the page displays incorrectly.

Comment: @valepu,yes, when i resize my browser window, it can show correctly! For grid  i use the $scope.gridOptions.ngGrid.buildColumns(), it show correctly! Thank u very much!

Comment: @valepu. i found another one fixed this issue, using nf-if instead of ng-show. what do u think is the reason?

Comment: because ng-if recreates the table (that is, the DOM object) from scratch instead of just hiding it in the DOM, so you get the call to rebuild the table for free when you show it with ng-if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ng-grid and ui-grid don't automatically update the table when hidden or shown. By calling `gridApi.core.refresh();` (for ui-grid) and `gridOptions.ngGrid.buildColumns();` (for ng-grid) you force the library to rebuild the table according to the current DOM situation

Answer (score 5):

i also find a solution: use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`/`ng-hide`, like this:

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions" ng-if="flag"></div>
```

Using `ng-if` also fiexed it for me!

Answer (score 5):

While I realize this question has aged, none of the solutions worked for me as of today. However, using the ui-grid-auto-resize attribute on my element worked like a charm.

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-auto-resize></div>
```

Comment: As per the docs http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/108_hidden_grids setting a width and height worked for me.